# How to fix "mbind: Operation not permitted" in mysql error log

Tags: docker, nginx, ubuntu-18.04, mysql-8.0

I have a problem with my MySQL error log which currently mostly consists of "mbind: Operation not permitted" lines (see below). Why does it happen and how do I fix it?

It's the "mostly" part that bothers me. As you can see below, not all lines are "mbind: Operation not permitted". I suspect that MySQL query errors should be instead of that line, but for some reason they can't be written into the file.

MySQL itself is a Docker container where log files are volumed via:

```
volumes:
- ./mysql/log:/var/log/mysql
```

What's interesting is that:

- "docker logs mysql_container" shows nothing...
- slow.log, which resides in the same volume folder, is completely OK and has real slow log lines in it, no "mbind: Operation not permitted" whatsoever!
- same as slow.log goes to general.log — no problem here, either

Any ideas? Thank you in advance.

```
2019-04-07T12:56:22.478504Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
2019-04-07T12:56:22.478533Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax 'expire-logs-days' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use binlog_expire_logs_seconds instead.
2019-04-07T12:56:22.478605Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.15) starting as process 1
2019-04-07T12:56:22.480115Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013242] [Server] --character-set-server: 'utf8' is currently an alias for the character set UTF8MB3, but will be an alias for UTF8MB4 in a future release. Please consider using UTF8MB4 in order to be unambiguous.
2019-04-07T12:56:22.480122Z 0 [Warning] [MY-013244] [Server] --collation-server: 'utf8_general_ci' is a collation of the deprecated character set UTF8MB3. Please consider using UTF8MB4 with an appropriate collation instead.
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
mbind: Operation not permitted
[same line goes forever]
```

P.S. MySQL starts and runs well, no problem with that. It's just this error.log that keeps bothering me and prevents me from seeing actual errors.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

Add the capability `CAP_SYS_NICE` to your container until MySQL server can handle the error itself "silently".

```yaml
service:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.15
    # ...
    cap_add:
      - SYS_NICE  # CAP_SYS_NICE
```

If you don't have `docker-compose`, then you can define `CAP_SYS_NICE` via

```bash
docker run --cap-add=sys_nice -d mysql
```

References:

- Docker Seccomp security profiles: https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/
- Docker resource constraints: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/

Comment: Is anyone aware of any issues with this solution? Can this cause the hardware device (not the container) to hang completely/crash? I can see that this allows MySQL to hang the system from  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/455084/giving-users-scheduling-privileges

Comment: Generally speaking, when a process is allowed to change its priority or niceness, it can set itself in an ultra high priority and be scheduled on the CPU more often than all other processes. So yes there is a risk that the process could starve other processes on the host when priority/niceness is chosen poorly. But so far I have never experienced such a problem with MySQL. Maybe am I not using the feature that needs this?

Comment: In case you are using Docker Stack/Swarm, `cap_add`/`security_opt` is not supported (https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/25885).

Comment: why is this happening? I hadn't problems in the past with mysql, and the solution doesn't seem safe, is docker mysql image v8 specific problem? is there going to be a better solution later and this is a quick fix?

Comment: it didn't work, i'd change to v5.7 because it's for test anyway, i hope this isn't going happen on production... :)

Comment: So what exactly is behind this problem?

Comment: Without CAP_SYS_NICE enabled, MySQL won't be able to handle thread priorities, and I guess you will then loose a new feature introduced with MySQL 8 (I believe Resource Groups https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resource-groups.html). MySQL should warn us *once* during startup. Instead (not sure whether it is still the case nowadays), it fills the disk with this message.

Comment: So I'm using MySQL 8.0 and the error message persists... Is this solution only applicable for 5.7? Anyone knows if another CAP solves this issue?

Comment: `- SYS_NICE  **# CAP_SYS_NICE**`

Documentation of the year award has been granted

Comment: @LaurentGosselin Explaining the error would be useful in the answer itself.

Comment: How do we do the same while building the image with `docker build`?

Answer (score 14):

Adding the `security_opt` option in docker-compose.yml helped to solve this problem:

```
database:
  image: mysql:latest
  container_name: mysql_0
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  security_opt:
    - seccomp:unconfined
```

Comment: I would avoid disabling the security profile completely and add the minimum extra rights

Comment: what does it look like to add the minimum extra rights @LaurentGosselin

Comment: @JosephAstrahan I guess he meant [his own answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55706057/2543244) posted 2 minutes earlier