# Docker swarm service security capabilities

Tags: mysql, docker-swarm

There available some security and resource constraint configuration for docker container applied by running for example `docker run -it --cap-add=sys_nice some_image`

- https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/seccomp/
- https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/resource_constraints/

Is there way to apply constraints for docker swarm service? `docker service create --cap-add=sys_nice some_image` fails with message: "unknown flag: --cap-add"

EDIT1:
I need to resolve issue mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55559386/how-to-fix-mbind-operation-not-permitted-in-mysql-error-log)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support `--cap-add` in swarm mode was added recently in docker/cli master branch
https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/2687.
Not sure that the update was added to the stable version.

Comment: The pull request says Milestone 20.03.0. Current stable version is 19.03.x. Hopefully that's in the near future.